# Использование словаря как структуры с уникальными значениями это нормальная практика?

Tags: c#

Есть код, который иногда генерирует ошибки, их надо потом вывести на экран, но проблема в том что ошибки бывает повторяются и на экране возникает много одинаковых значений, я использовал такой костыль и применил сообщения об ошибках как ключ к словарю, это нормально или я гоню?

```
Dictionary<string, int> errorMessage new Dictionary<string, int>();

//...

errorMessage[Message] = code;
```

Это не первый случай использования мной словаря как списка уникальных значений, еще я применил его в определении повторяющихся строк в таблице.
Мне кажется что код не очень правильно спроектирован и можно как то более элегантно решить?

```
Dictionary<string,int> duplicateProduct = new Dictionary<string, int>();
private void findDuplicates()
{
    string tradeName = string.Empty;

    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        tradeName = row[tradeColumn].ToString();
        DataRow[] filteredRows = dataTable.Select(string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", tradeColumn, tradeName));
        if(filteredRows.Length > 1)
        {
            duplicateProduct[tradeName] = 1;
        }
    }
}
private void removeDuplicates()
{
    foreach (var product in duplicateProduct)
    {
        DataRow[] filteredRows = dataTable.Select(string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", tradeColumn, product.Key));
        dataTable.Rows.Remove(minRow(filteredRows));
    }
}
```

То есть по сути из всего словаря я использую только KEY а VALUE мне как бы и не к чему, это меня и беспокоит.

Comment: Почему тогда не `HashSet<string>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну например можно использовать просто `HashSet<string>`:

```
HashSet<string> duplicateProduct = new HashSet<string>();
private void findDuplicates()
{
    string tradeName = string.Empty;

    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        tradeName = row[tradeColumn].ToString();
        DataRow[] filteredRows =
            dataTable.Select(string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", tradeColumn, tradeName));
        if(filteredRows.Length > 1)
        {
            duplicateProduct.Add(tradeName);
        }
    }
}

private void removeDuplicates()
{
    foreach (var product in duplicateProduct)
    {
        DataRow[] filteredRows =
            dataTable.Select(string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", tradeColumn, product));
        dataTable.Rows.Remove(minRow(filteredRows));
    }
}
```

(Я не проверял правильность кода, работающего с базой данных.)

Comment: Все работает, спасибо, я просто затупил и забыл что существует хеш.